# How to calculate the UDP input Bitrate and Output Bitrate

Tags: networking, server, bash, ffmpeg, bandwidth

How to Calculate the UDP Bitrate and information(UDP Input bitrate and UDP Output bitrate)

Like ffprobe

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://269.1.1.104:1001':
  Duration: N/A, start: 25881.121689, bitrate: N/A
  Program 40
    Metadata:
      service_name    : PUBLIC MUSIC
      service_provider: Harmonic
    Stream #0:0[0xfa1]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0xfa2](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
```

But ffprobe doesn't work all the time ...

So is there any other solution any tools or any commands...

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the TSDuck toolkit and use this command `--debug`

`tsp --debug -I ip 269.1.1.104:1001 -O drop`

-I = input UPD ip

```
* Debug: ip: initial buffer load: 7 packets, 1,316 bytes
* ip: unknown initial input bitrate
* Debug: ip: input thread started
* Debug: drop: output thread started
* Debug: control commands: debug level set to 1
* Debug: control commands: found 0 packet processor plugins
* Debug: ip: input: got bitrate 2,976,965 b/s
* Debug: ip: input: got bitrate 3,041,196 b/s
* Debug: ip: input: got bitrate 3,101,650 b/s
```

Comment: Several of the options listed here do not exist for tsp that I can install on 22.04

Answer (score 0):

install this tool

```
sudo apt-get install lsof
```

and use this command where 1001 is a port

```
lsof -i :1001
```

Comment: Thanks @gopal. it was working well but.... it was calculate the whole UDP of the port ... i want calculate the particular one UDP of the Port